# Quick regex to match a paterrn and replace it with null/empty

Tags: regex, windows-7, file-rename

I have a folder with a huge number of files and I need to rename them. I'm using a bulk/batch renaming utilty: http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php

It allows for RegEx patern matching and replacing.

Here is are couple of sample file names:

- ...
- 04-067 - Name of File I need **(1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s)**.avi
- 04-068 - Name of File I need **(1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s)**.avi
- 04-069 - Name of File I need **(1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s)**.avi
- 04-070 - Name of File I need **(1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s)**.avi
- 04-071 - Name of File I need **(1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s)**.avi
- 04-072 - Name of File I need **(1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s)**.avi
- 04-073 - Name of File I need **(1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s)**.avi
- ...

I need to remove the `(19*` part and keep the `.avi` so that new names are as follows:

- ...
- 04-067 - Name of File I need.avi
- 04-068 - Name of File I need.avi
- 04-069 - Name of File I need.avi
- 04-070 - Name of File I need.avi
- 04-071 - Name of File I need.avi
- 04-072 - Name of File I need.avi
- 04-073 - Name of File I need.avi
- ...

The name of files sometimes contain a (abc) too but the `(19*` are always present:

04-067 - Name of File I need (Colored) (3D) `(1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s)`.avi

Any quick help for such a regex?

Update:
Here is an image (http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/6275/bulkrenameutility.png) : [image: Screenshot]

Regards.

Comment: The utility I'm using is free, BTW..

Comment: the answers provided should work. From webpage `However, the syntax supported by this program is the same as that offered
by PERL 5. The precise implementation is via the PCRE Library, and (at the time of writing) full
notes on the Perl Regular Expression syntax can be found here.` what exactly did you type in?

Comment: @Fredrik Here is a snap: http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/6275/bulkrenameutility.png The second column shows the after effects. I tried with ext included also and typed stuff to replace with but no match :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\s*\(19.*\.avi` with `.avi`

Comment: @Hassan, should work just fine. Show us what code/command you are using.

Comment: @Hassan, this regex would work fine if it was supported by your tool, but we don't know if it is.

Comment: @Qtax can u think of another utility for me? I'm far away from my devb machine or else I'd have this done by now :(

Comment: @Hassan: From what I can see on your screenshot you are not even trying the regex the way I wrote it. For example, the `/slashes/` are wrong, you don't need them.

Comment: If you have Perl, test with this command: `perl -e "while(<*.avi>){ $a = $_; print qq'$a => $_' if s/\s*\(19.*\.avi$/.avi/}"`, to rename run this one: `perl -e "while(<*.avi>){ $a = $_; rename $a, $_ if s/\s*\(19.*\.avi$/.avi/}"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the tool you are referring to but this regexp should work

```
/ (.*)/
```

there is a space before the first parenthesis, and then replace it with an empty string. Perhaps "(" needs to be escaped in your tool.

tested using sed:

```
$ echo '04-067 - Name of File I need (1943) (Aplha, Xtra, Info) [ExtraA] (15m34s).avi' | sed 's/ (.*)//'
04-067 - Name of File I need.avi
```

Comment: If it's a tool from 1984, maybe it would do what you mean. But it still wouldn't work. ;)

Comment: @Qtax Lol. The tool is new. The files are prety old balck&White episodes.

Comment: The result filename is just blank

Comment: @Hassan, my comment was @Fredrik

Comment: Your explaination makes perfect sense. Maybe something is wrong with the utility I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match all the filenames containing a year between parentheses `/(\s*19.*\.avi$/i` . Then, replace the matched string  with `.avi` .

Comment: I have an option to include the extension(s) or exclude them. Toggling either failed and also, I tried a modified version too: `/\(.*?\)\s*\(19.*\)$/i`. No avail.